# How to store JSON from API with pymsql? Chatbot Dialogflow with python

Tags: python, json, dialogflow-es

I have some problem. I make chatbot dialogflow with fulfillment python and mysql. The chatbot must have connection to mysql. There are 2 tables in my database, inbox and outbox. Table inbox contain of user input and table outbox contain of response from API (like omdbapi.com). How to store user input from dialoglow and data json from API with pymsql for chatbot? Here the code. The code work, but missing of connection to database. I will grateful if you help my task. Thank you

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os
import dialogflow
import requests
import json
from db_con import *

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

@app.route('/get_movie_detail', methods=['POST'])
def get_movie_detail():
        data = request.get_json(silent=True)
        movie = data['queryResult']['parameters']['movie']
        api_key = os.getenv('OMDB_API_KEY')
        movie_detail = requests.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={0}&apikey={1}'.format(movie, api_key)).content
        movie_detail = json.loads(movie_detail)
        response =  """
            Title : {0}
            Released: {1}
            Actors: {2}
            Plot: {3}
            Runtime: {4}
            Genre: {5}
        """.format(movie_detail['Title'], movie_detail['Released'], movie_detail['Actors'], movie_detail['Plot'], movie_detail['Runtime'], movie_detail['Genre'])

        reply = {
            "fulfillmentText": response,
        }
        return jsonify(reply)
```